# How to run a command in a bash script from a loop with different arguments simultaneously in the background, while formatting the output

Tags: linux, bash, shell

The following snippet will run within the script, but it takes a long time for each loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
….
some_command $A $B $C | awk ‘{print$1}’ | while read -r var1; do
    printf "\n$var1 \n"
    printf "\n"
    other_command $var1
    printf "\n"
done
….
```

I tried running this, but the printf statements will run before the other_command, which is used to make the output a little more readable.

```
#!/bin/bash
….
some_command $A $B $C | awk ‘{print$1}’ | while read -r var1; do
    printf "\n$var1 \n"
    printf "\n"|
    other_command $var1 &
    printf "\n"
done
wait 
….
```

If I run just other_command with the & in loop I get the desired result but it it not very readable.

Comment: Your code has a number of formatting errors (missing quotes, curly quotes, unpaired parentheses, etc) which detract from your actual question and make it harder to understand what exactly you need help with; please clean it up.

Comment: @tripleee Thank. I did. Working off my phone.

Comment: You can run each iteration in a subshell `( echo stuff; command; more stuff ) &` but you will still get mixed output if two background commands finish at roughly the same time. Maybe a better solution would be to put each result in a temporary file and then format them when they are all done.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Take a look at GNU parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to move the long running command into a function, and call this function multiple times as child processes. This way they can run in parallel. Inside the function, the output from the command is first written into a local variable, and only printed in one go after the command is done.

```
#!/bin/bash

function do_something () {
  local OUTPUT="$(other_command "$var1")"
  printf "\n%s\n\n%s\n" "$1" "$OUTPUT";
}

some_command "$A" "$B" "$C" | while read -r "var1" "_";
do
  do_something "$var1" &
done

wait
```

Please note that the order of the output will (probably) be different on every call, which is inherent to parallel execution.

Comment: You'll want to get rid of the Awk call, too; `read` is eminently able to split on whitespace by itself - viz `read -r var1 _` where you then leave the second variable `_` unused. The lone underscore is a common convention for dummy variables like this.

Comment: And quoting the variable name in `read` is somewhat pointless, as well as potentially misleading. There is no way to name a variable so that its name would require quoting.

Comment: You should use `printf` with a format string and the variables as (quoted) additional arguments; otherwise, it will be an error for either variable to contain a percent sign.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.

Comment: This is similar to a solution I tried earlier. It does yield an increased performance for me by about 32%, but it does drop to the cli mid script, and then push the rest out to stdout.

Comment: Sounds like a buffer issue.

Comment: I am marking this question as answered, but it does raise a separate issue of the variable only being local to that subshell, and while this does strictly provide a solution for the question, it ultimately was not a solution.  Kudos to @tripleee.

Comment: And Kudos to @Corubba. Thanks.