# Parallelized output to the console

Tags: bash

Is there a way to keep output from a background process from showing up in the middle of the output of another process?

I have a script `status_update.sh` which periodically queries some status on a separate host machine and prints an update line if it changes.

I want to run this script in parallel for multiple hosts:

```
#!/bin/bash

status_update.sh -h host1 &
status_update.sh -h host2 &
status_update.sh -h host3 &
status_update.sh -h host4 &

echo "hit any key to quit"
read -n 1 CHAR

killall status_update.sh
```

The problem I'm having is that the updates from one process shows up in the middle of the output from another process.  Is there a way to keep the output separated on different lines?

Comment: See also this recent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35113225/how-to-run-a-command-in-a-bash-script-from-a-loop-with-different-arguments-simul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the only way to ensure that writes don't overlap is to use a mutex of some sort.  This is a pain to implement in the shell, and probably shouldn't be done.  Instead, write status_update.sh to block on a mutex and pass a name as a parameter, and then have status_update.sh block any write until it gets the mutex.   One way to potentially mitigate the problem without using a mutex is to pipe everything to cat, which can help ensure that fewer write system calls are made (if 20 writes of size 5 are made rather than 1 write of size 100, there is more opportunity for writes to be interleaved).  That is, try:

```
#!/bin/bash

status_update.sh -h host1 | cat &
status_update.sh -h host2 | cat &
status_update.sh -h host3 | cat &
status_update.sh -h host4 | cat &
```

Comment: If I got you correctly, you may use the `stdbuf` command instead. However at the end it is probaly better to store the output in a temporary file/pipe per process and display that after the processes have finished. Of course for long running processes this might not be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, `| cat &` didn't work.  I think its because the status line is printed out using multiple `printf` commands.  However, I looked into lock files and `flock` can offer the mutex ability you recommend.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using **GNU Parallel** to give you a named mutex that guards `echo` commands:

```
sem --id MyMutex echo something
```

That way only a single instance of `echo` can run at a time. See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/sem.html).